# Turn s something around on someone...... Is it like "turning something back on someone"?

Tags: word-usage

> I'm off the clock, Mr. Stock," I told him, leaning back on my chair so it balanced on two legs.
>
> "So? Don't you respect the place you work? Is that the kind of person you want to be?" he snapped.
>
> "How did he **turn that around on me**?" I wondered.

What does it exactly mean here? Is it something like directing the conversation towards a person?

And is it synonymous to "turn something back on someone"? (Though I guess this is used to when the answerer doesn't answer the question but flips the question back around on the questioner.)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it means that person A thought he was winning the conflict with Mr Stock by saying he was off the clock. (Meaning he did not have to act professionally as his work time was over).

The reply Mr Stock gave him was that it shows a lack of respect regardless of working hour. By which Mr Stock effectively won the discussion.

The 'turning around' in this case points to who was "right" in the conflict. First Person A thought he was, but after Mr Stock's answer, he still lost.

I would not consider them to be synonyms, but Bee has explained that.

Answer (score 0):

To turn your back on something - is quite different to, turning something around.

> Turn around - Usually means to change the plan to make something successful [Ref.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/turn-around)

In your case, it's a little different, I think it's best to read through [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338538/word-for-turning-a-situation-around-on-someone) which is asking a very similar question and explains it a lot better than I can!

> Turn your back on someone - means to ignore or abandon them (esspecially in their time of need). [Ref.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+your+back+on+somebody)